# Verify whether the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is open or closed (or both) on $\mathbb{R^2}$ with standard Euclidean metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How does this set look like? How do we choose an $\epsilon$ radius?

Comment: It is closed but not open.

Comment: Think about the set $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$, the lattice of integer points in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Think about whether this is open or closed. Are there any open balls contained in this set at all? Now, think about $\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{Z}$; you're limiting to positive integers in the first coordinate. That is, you're getting rid of all the points to the left of the $y$-axis.

Comment: It looks like a bunch of dots in a rectangular grid.  You can choose $\epsilon$ to be anything.  Notice that if $x=(a,b)\in \mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ then the nearest four points in $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ are $(a,b+1),(a+1,b),(a,b-1)$ and $(a-1,b)$ the they are all a distance of $1$ away.  So what can you say if you choose $\epsilon < 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a real number $x$ is not an integer then it lies striclty between two consecutive integers, say $n <x<n+1$. Then $|y-x| <\min \{x-n,n+1-x\}$ implies that $y$ is not an integer. Use this idea to show that the complement of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ is open. Hence $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ is closed. It is not open because $(1,0)$ belongs to this set and every open ball around this point contains points of the form $(1,\frac 1 k)$ which don't belong to $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z$ .

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, since for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, we may find an open ball $G$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $G/ \lbrace (x,y) \rbrace \cap \mathbb{N}$ is empty set. For any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, define $G=\lbrace (a,b):d((a,b),(x,y))<1\rbrace$. Then clearly $G$ is open and it also contains $(x,y)$ such that $G/ \lbrace (x,y) \rbrace \cap \mathbb{N}$ is empty. Therefore any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is not alimit point of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ or in other words $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ contains each of its limit points. Hence it is closed. It is not closed since $(1,1)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ but any open set containing $(1,1)$ must contains some irrationals so that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ can not be open.

Proceeding in a similar way may go for $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: "Usimg Archimedian property we may find appropriate ϵ such that G satisfies required condition."  Why make it so hard?  Any $\epsilon \le 1$ will do.

Comment: @fleablood Yes sir, this will work, actually I was confused with the definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Thanks for reminding me, I have edited my answer.